# Click one Release

Tags: clickonce

I have a VB .Net windows application and it is launched successfully if the url is clicked. Without any issues.

Now i want to know the user, who download my application by program and also I want to control the users.

So that there need to be an authentic details to the user to download the application.

Is there any possible way to accomplish this problem?
Any solution or suggestions are appreciable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your English is a little broken. I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to track each user that downloads it? What does 'control the users' mean? Also, I'm at a lost of what 'authentic details' you are referring to; it seems you have answered your own question in that sentence anyways.

Comment: I think he wants to have users authenticate before they are allowed to download his application.

Answer (score 0):

Publish it in a location you need to be authenticated to see like a network share

Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

Like to said, put it in a location that requires authentication. I was thinking a website. If no membership, maybe make them fill out the registration form before getting the link to download. You can log their IP address, but you can't get anymore info without them giving it to you.

Otherwise, you can create a registration feature in your application. Maybe require registation after 30 days ( or right away). Create a form the user must fill out - when they register, have it send a web service call and store the registration info.